# How to explicitly specify the series for plotted data-points in Swift Charts without using .XXX(by:) API?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

I'm Curious, is there a way to specify the Series that Swift Chart data belongs to, if you can't use API like [`.symbol(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chartcontent/symbol(by:)) and [`foregroundStyle(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chartcontent/foregroundstyle(by:)) (ie any of the ones listed in Apple Docs under the heading "Encoding data into mark characteristics").

The situation I have is that I'm overriding symbol and foregroundStyle in my chart, so I can't use the above options that give automatic symbol and style, but also specify the series for the data. So I'm looking for another function that will directly indicate to Swift Charts what the series is, rather than doing that as a side-effect of some other action.

Here's some code to show the problem (for simplicity I've omitted symbols):

```swift
import Charts

struct ExplicitSeries: View {
    func chartPoint(x: Double, y: Double, series: Int) -> some ChartContent {
        LineMark(
            x: .value("Day", x),
            y: .value("Total", y)
        )
//        .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Count", "Series \(series)"))
        .foregroundStyle( series == 0 ? Color.blue : Color.green)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            chartPoint(x: 0, y: 0, series: 0)
            chartPoint(x: 1, y: 1, series: 0)
            chartPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5, series: 1)
            chartPoint(x: 1, y: 0, series: 1)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

And here's what the result looks like:

[image: chart that doesn't know about series]

Instead of two distinct series (one blue and one green), we have a single series of blue. Uncommenting the `.foregroundStyle(by:)` line will give the result I'm looking for (but without ability to override the colors):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your line marks with a `series:` parameter:

```
LineMark(
    x: .value("Day", x),
    y: .value("Total", y),
    series: .value("Series", series)
)
.foregroundStyle(series == 0 ? Color.red : Color.purple)
```

Now it will work.

---

Alternatively, you can use one of the [`chartForegroundStyleScale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/chartforegroundstylescale(_:)) modifiers on the `Chart`, in addition to `foregroundStyle(by:)`.

On the `LineMark`, do:

```
.foregroundStyle(by: .value("Series", series))
```

On the `Chart`, you can give it a dictionary representing the mapping of the possible values of `series`, to the colors you want:

```
.chartForegroundStyleScale([
    0: Color.red,
    1: Color.purple
])
```

It is also possible to pass [a `(some Plottable) -> some ShapeStyle` function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/chartforegroundstylescale(mapping:)).

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! It's a bit round-about, but it looks like it's the way to go. If you don't mind, could you expand on the last part about `(some Plottable) -> some ShapeStyle`? I don't follow.

Comment: @CuriousJorge I'm just referring to [this other overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/chartforegroundstylescale(mapping:)) of `chartForegroundStyleScale`.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. All clear now!